# Not able to get the page id where the binary content resides during binary indexing - Integrating Search module in SDL DXA 2

Tags: dxa, si4t, dxa-2.0

**We are trying to implement Search module in SDL DXA 2 and integrate it with the elastic search. When we publish a page which has binary content, from the logs we could find that the binary indexing was taking place first and after that the page content.**

1. Why is binary indexing taking place before the page indexing?
2. Also from the binary indexing process is there a way I can get the page id of the actual page it is residing because I need this info as well for indexing.
3. While indexing the page is there any way to get the embedded schema components? For eg: if my page has a component with text fields, date, embedded media schema etc, right now page indexing only provides the text from all these data fields clubbed together. Is there a way I can get other fields like the date, embedded media etc so that I can call the custom methods for binary indexing from here itself?
4. Is there any other way to get the media files like pdf or it's component id from the page index?

**Log files: We can see that binary indexing is taking place 1st and then page indexing**

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Adding binaries to elastic.

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 DEBUG ElasticIndexer - Dispatching binary content to elastic.

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Indexing binary with Id: binary:5-4269, and URL Path:/xxx/xxx.pdf

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - data.getPublicationItemId() 5

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - data.getIndexUrl() /xxx/xxx.pdf

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - data.getFileSize() 42025

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - data.getFileType() pdf

2018-03-15 13:58:22,637 INFO  ElasticIndexer - data.getFileName() xxx.pdf

2018-03-15 13:58:25,673 TRACE ElasticIndexer - inside processItemUpdates elastic

2018-03-15 13:58:25,674 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Adding pages and component presentations to elastic in batches of 10

2018-03-15 13:58:25,678 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Adding Id: tcm:5-304-64

2018-03-15 13:58:25,678 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: summary: xxx.

2018-03-15 13:58:25,678 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: parentsgid: 66

2018-03-15 13:58:25,678 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: itemtype: 64

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: schemaid: 62

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: sgid: 66

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: sgid: 63

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: sgid: 4

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: title: xxx

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: publicationid: 5

2018-03-15 13:58:25,679 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: type: 0

2018-03-15 13:58:25,680 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: body: xxx

2018-03-15 13:58:25,680 TRACE ElasticIndexer - Adding: url: /xxx/xxx/xxx.html

2018-03-15 13:58:25,680 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Dispatching documents in 1 steps.

2018-03-15 13:58:25,682 INFO  ElasticIndexer - Clearing out registers.

**This is how the indexing XML data looks like:**

```
<indexdata>
<url>/xxx/xxx/xxx.html</url>
<title>xxx</title>
<publicationid>5</publicationid>
<schemaid>62</schemaid>
<itemtype>64</itemtype>
<parentsgid>66</parentsgid>
<sgid>66</sgid>
<sgid>63</sgid>
<sgid>4</sgid>
<type>0</type>
<body>xxx</body>
<custom>
    <summary>xxx</summary>
</custom>
</indexdata>
```

Comment: you can able to include custom fields IN Filed mapping and Link Fields to Embed in the TBB, then you can able to see those fields data in the custom section in the indexing XML

Comment: Please edit your questions to add a bit more detail about what you are trying to do exactly with search functionality Is there any specific reason looking to index the binaries used on the pages?

Comment: Yes, we are trying to index the binaries used on the pages. While doing so we are not getting the pageid where the binary resides.

Comment: @Velmurugan to answer your query the business requirement is that if the search term is found in some PDF files or other documents then the search results page should display the title and link of the page referencing the PDF (in addition to showing the PDF and its link).

Answer (score 1):

**An answer to question1:**

AFAIK - Based on the transaction first will fire the dependencies used on the page and then page object will process to commit the changes.

But It doesn't mean that it will be indexing the same way, it can be customized.

If you look at the **[SolrIndexer.java](https://github.com/SI4T/Solr/blob/master/src/main/java/org/si4t/solr/SolrIndexer.java)** in the **commit** method, It's indexing in the following orders.

```
this.commitAddContentToSolr(this.itemAdds);
this.commitAddBinariesToSolr();
this.removeItemsFromSolr();
this.processItemUpdates();
```

**An answer to question2:**

I'm afraid, It's not possible. I'm not sure it's possible to get out-of-box by backtracking based on binary item-reference-id to get the component Id to find out the page Id.

**An answer to question3:**

In the **Generate Index Data** TBB you can able to include custom fields In Filed mapping and Link Fields to Embed in the TBB, then you can able to see those fields data in the custom section in the indexing XML.

Regarding binary indexing on elastic search, I'm not sure about Is it supported for binary content searchable.

**[Binary datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/binary.html)** - In elastic search

The binary type accepts a binary value as a Base64 encoded string. The field is not stored by default and is not searchable:

I hope it helps.